# PHP Fatal error: [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini

Tags: php

When i am trying to start Apache, the following error appears in the Apache error log:

> PHP Fatal error: [ionCube Loader]  The Loader must appear as the first
>   entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error message itself its clear what is the error. Please do some research before posting on StackOverflow.

Zend extensions can be loaded directly from `/etc/php.ini` file or included from `/etc/php.d/` directory.

In the following example, this ionCube line must appear before any Zend configuration sections. These sections usually begin with `[Zend]` so they should be easy to see:

> zend_extension=/usr/lib/ioncube/php_ioncube_loader_lin_X.X.so

If extensions are loaded from `/etc/php.d`, they are loaded in alphabetical order. Usually the ionCube file is named `/etc/php.d/ioncube.ini` and Zend is `/etc/php.d/zend.ini`. In this scenario, it should not present a problem (and if it does, just rename the ini file or add numerical prefix i.e. `50-ioncube.ini`.

Finally, make sure that ionCube loader is loaded only once. The following command should only return one result:

> grep 'zend_extension.*ioncube' /etc/php.ini /etc/php.d/*

If you make any configuration changes, always be sure to restart Apache:

> /etc/init.d/httpd restart

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404974/resolve-apache-error:-%22php-fatal-error:-%5Bioncube-loader%5D%22

Comment: If you use ubuntu `phpenmod ioncube` or similar to enable the module, then double check the symlink order in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d` and others. `10-opcache.ini` get higher priority than `20-ioncube.ini` causing this issue. ioncube better be at the top

Answer (score 6):

Came to this thread when looking for this error, as @Hari Swaminathan said.

> If extensions are loaded from /etc/php.d, they are loaded in alphabetical order

I got the error on a docker setup. So naming ini file like `00-ioncube.ini` solved the problem

Comment: This is still applicable for docker for my `Laravel sail` setup.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because of an incorrect extension order in PHP configuration. Read [this website](http://kb.odin.com/en/1520) may help you.
You must load ioncube with higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on a docker local development

Was able to ADD a ioncube specific ini file and module file

```
# Add ioncube
ADD etc/ioncube_loader_lin_7.2.so $PHP_EXT_DIR/ioncube_loader_lin_7.2.so

# Add php overrides
ADD etc/docker-php-ext-ioncube.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/docker-php-ext-ioncube.ini
```

Thanks @davidmpaz